# aws-shell not working in Ubuntu 20, on AWS Lightsail

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, aws-shell

I've created AWS Lightsail instance with Ubuntu 20.04, installed python3 and pip3.
I installed AWS Shell tool using `pip3 install aws-shell` command.
However, when I try to run it, it hangs and outputs `Killed` after several minutes.

This is how it looks like:

```
root@ip-...:/home/ubuntu# aws-shell
First run, creating autocomplete index...
Killed
root@ip-...:/home/ubuntu# aws-shell
First run, creating autocomplete index...
Killed
```

On **Metrics** page of AWS Lightsail it shows CPU utilization spike in **Burstable zone**.
So I'm quite sad that this just wastes CPU quota by loading CPU for several minutes and doesn't work.

I've done the same steps on Ubuntu 16.0 on virtual machine and it worked there fine. So I'm completely lost here and don't know how can I fix it. Tried to google this problem and didn't find anything related.

UPD: also I've just tried to use python 2.7 version to install aws-shell, it still doesn't work. So it doesn't work for both python 3.8.5 and 2.7.18

Answer (score 0):

The `aws-shell` tool should be used on local machine, instead of on AWS Lightsail instance.
I wish it had warning or info message about it, besides me knowing now that it was an incorrect endeavor.